# Numba LLVM: Weird behaviour Error on decimal representation

Tags: python, llvm, numba

I'm using numba (numba-0.20.0-n) in some of my python projects. Compiling fails for a certain routine

```
python: APFloat.cpp:273: 
void interpretDecimal(
llvm::StringRef::iterator, llvm::StringRef::iterator, decimalInfo*): 
Zusicherung »(*p == 'e' || *p == 'E') && "Invalid character in significand"« 
nicht erfüllt.
Abgebrochen (Speicherabzug geschrieben)
```

Sorry for the German output, but if I set the system language (Ubuntu 14.04 64bit) to English by

```
export LC_ALL=C
```

the error goes away. I suspect that the decimal representation causes some weird behavior, since in Germany the comma "," instead of the dot "." is used to separate digits. Of course, in my code I only use the dot as separator and I assumed that would be the case for all programming languages. Any ideas?

**Edit:** 
Maybe the actual code helps some of you. Be aware that the error occurs only when the system language is German (or at least not English):

```
from numba import jit
import numpy as np

@jit( nopython = True )
def numba_shift(array, shift):
    '''
    if shift > 0 -> left shift
    if shift < 0 -> right shift
    '''
    if shift > 0:
        for k in xrange(array.shape[0]):
            #~ print k + shift, array.shape[0]
            if k + shift >= array.shape[0] or k + shift < 0:
                array[k] = 0
            else:
                array[k] = array[k+shift]
    else:
        for k in range(array.shape[0]-1,-1,-1):
            #~ print k + shift, array.shape[0]
            if k + shift >= array.shape[0] or k + shift < 0:
                array[k] = 0
            else:
                array[k] = array[k+shift]

    return array            

@jit(nopython = True )
def numba_shift_image(image, shift, rows, cols ):
    for row in xrange(rows):
        shift = (row - rows / 2) * shift
        new_row = np.zeros(cols)
        for k in xrange(cols):
            new_row[k] = image[row, k]
        new_row = numba_shift(new_row, shift)
        for k in xrange(cols):
            image[row, k] = new_row[k]

    return image 

    a = np.random.random((100,100))
    b = numba_shift_image(a, 2, 100, 100)
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem but in my case the language is Portuguese. Using `export LC_ALL=C` works for me as well. This didn't happen before so it might be something with an update to LLVM on Anaconda?

Comment: OK, I ran some tests with different versions of numba and LLVM and the problem seems to have appeared with `llvmlite=0.5.0`. Using `numba=0.18.2` and `llvmlite=0.4.0` works perfectly.

Comment: Good to know, seems like a regression bug then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug seems to be fixed after the last update of the following packages in anaconda:

llvmlite:       0.6.0-py27_0      --> 0.7.0-py27_3
numba:          0.20.0-np19py27_0 --> 0.21.0-np19py27_0